# Behaviour of a continuous function that is always smaller than another

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity

Let there be two continuous functions $f,g$ on $[0,1]$ such that $0<g(x)<f(x) \forall x $, why is it true that we can always find a $\lambda$ such that $\lambda g(x) \leq f(x) \forall x \in [0,1]$? More importantly, why is this fact important? Since my professor stressed this fact so many times.

Comment: Thank everyone for their answers. But since my analysis course is an intro course that does not cover compactness, can I prove what is stated in terms of sequences? I asked the professor, he replied: 'construct a sequence from the converse of the statement'.

Comment: Have you learn this fact yet: "If $a_n$ is a bounded sequence, then it has a converging subsequence." ?

Comment: Yes, I actually tried. Assume the converse, and consider $n>2$, then there exists $x_n$ such that $ng(x_n)>f(x_n)$ and $x_n$ as a sequence is bounded and hence there exists a convergent subsequence. I also know from continuity that $g(x_{n_k})$ will converge to a point in $[0,1]$, but then I do not know how I should proceed.

Comment: What's the purpose of $ng(x_n)>f(x_n)$? This doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: Since the converse is $\forall \lambda >1$, there exists $x$ such that $\lambda g(x) > f(x)$, I was trying to construct a sequence from all the $x$ that satisfy $\lambda g(x) >f(x)$ by considering all $n$ starting from $n=2$.

Comment: It's better to try $\frac {n+1}n g(x_n)>f(x_n)$.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of compactness of $[0,1]$. Consider $f-g$. It is continuous and positive everywhere. Since its domain is compact, it attains its minimum value $m$. In other words, $f(x)-g(x)\geq m$ for all $x$ in $[0,1]$. You can use that to obtain $\lambda$.

Comment: I don't think you can easily compute $\lambda$ if you do it this way. Would you mind elaborate a bit more?

Comment: How about setting $\lambda = (m/2+\mathrm{max}g)/g$?

Answer (score 1):

I think you actually want $\lambda > 1$, else it's trivial if we can take $\lambda=1.$

Consider the function $h=f/g$. It is clear that $h$ is also continuous and that $h(x)>1$ for all $x\in[0,1]$. Since $[0,1]$ is a compact set, $h$ attains its minimum i.e. there is $x^* \in [0,1]$ such that 
$$h(x^*)=\min_{x\in[0,1]} h(x).$$

Since $h>1$ we must have $\min_{x\in[0,1]} \left(f(x)/g(x)\right) = h(x^*)>1$.

Finally, it is easy to see that $\lambda=\min_{x\in[0,1]} \left(f(x)/g(x)\right)$ satisfies the condition you want.

PS. As to why this fact is important to your professor one can only guess. What I can say is this "fact" doesn't hold if our domain is an unbounded interval or an open interval.